# replace css media query with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace CSS media queries with JavaScript so that I can use CSS animation on my home page (hero image) with text. I want the text to fade in. Looking for alternative, I concluded that js was the best (and easiest) way to accomplish this. I have tried both switch and if/else but run into too many syntax error with stuff I know too little about.*
HTML

JS switch
script>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

text = text.replace(new RegExp(replacement, 'g'), '');

    switch $(window).innerWidth() {
    case 0:
        max-width <= 320;
        break;
    case 1:
        max-width <= 480;
        var str = " indexPhoto_320.jpg";
        var res = str.replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg", "indexPhoto_450.jpg");
        break;
    case 2:
        max-width <= 768;
        var str = " indexPhoto_320.jpg";
        var res = str.replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg", "indexPhoto_835.jpg");
        break;
    case 3:
        max-width <= 1260;
        var str = " indexPhoto_320.jpg";
        var res = str.replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg", "indexPhoto_1000.jpg");
        break;                    
    case 4:
        max-width <= 1420;
        var str = " indexPhoto_320.jpg" ;
        var res = str.replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg", "indexPhoto_1000.jpg");
        break;
    case 4:
        max-width > 1420;   
        var str = " indexPhoto_320.jpg";
        var res = str.replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg", "indexPhoto_1200.jpg");
        break;                    
    default:
        break;
    }}
```

JS ifElse
 var intViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

```
$(document).ready(function() {


     if intViewportWidth  > 320 && <=480
         $("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg" width"320" height"474").      ("indexPhoto_450.jpg" width"450" height"630");

     else if intViewportWidth >480 && <=768 
         $("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg" width"320" height"474"). ("indexPhoto_450.jpg" width"450" height"630");



    else if intViewportWidth  >768 && <=1024
         $("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg" width"320" height"474"). ("indexPhoto_835.jpg" width"835" height"1024");
        var res = str.


    else if intViewportWidth  >1024 && <=1260
         $("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src") replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg" width"320" height"474"). ("indexPhoto_1000.jpg" width"1000" height"667");


    else if intViewportWidth  >1260 && <= 1420
         $("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src") replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg" width"320" height"474"). ("indexPhoto_1000.jpg" width"1000" height"667");


    else  
         $("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src") replace("indexPhoto_320.jpg" width"320" height"474"). ("indexPhoto_1200.jpg" width"1200" height"801");
            };
```

Any suggestions, help is appreciated. I've spent days puzzling over this stuff.

Loren

Comment: Please clarify what it is you are trying to do and why media queries don't accomplish this.

Comment: If you are using JQuery, then you want `$(window).width()` and if you are not using JQuery, then you want: `window.innerWidth`. You've got both syntaxes merged.

Comment: Your `switch` case is a bit off. The condition you'd like to evaluate should be your `case`, not *inside* it. And your second example, your `if` syntax is incorrect. It's `if(` *`condition`* `) {` *`code`* `} else if(` *`condition`* `) {` *`code`* `} else {` *`code`* `}`

Comment: I've tried many times to accomplish this with CSS but finally read i could not use animation on a background image which is what I have always had. maybe I need to rethink.